# Save and Load a catboost model with Caret in R

Tags: r, r-caret, catboost

I am able to train a Catboost model with caret (in Rstudio) and it works great.

```
my_catboost <- caret::train(x, y, 

              method=catboost.caret, 
              trControl=fitControl, 
              tuneGrid = param,
              metric = "ROC")
```

If I use the model to predict on new data in the same session, no issue, it works:

```
output <- caret::predict.train(my_catboost, newdata=x_testing, type="prob")
```

However, If I save the model and load it later (or save it, delete "my_catboost" and load), the function predict will crash R and Rstudio without error message and can't find anything in Rstudio log. After the load, I can see the model being created in the global Environment and it seems fine.

I tried the R function save and load, saveRDS and readRDS and both crashed

Thanks !

Comment: After tuning the model in caret, just save the final model: `my_catboost$finalModel` using `catboost::catboost.save_model` and load it using `catboost::catboost.load_model`. If you performed data transformations 
 using `preProcess` argument in `caret::train` things are a bit more complex. If you are interested in that I can add an answer if you can provide a reproducible example using an inbuilt data set. Also this should probably be posted as an [issue on github](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues).

Comment: Thanks @missuse. Rstudio crash on catboost::catboost.save_model. I opened a github issue here : https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/342#issuecomment-431256587

Comment: @missuse Let me know whether the tests I posted on github make sense. Otherwise we will try a way to have some code with inbuilt data.

Comment: You have misunderstood my comment check the answer I added. This should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have misunderstood my comment. Here is an answer using the inbuilt data set Sonar:

```
library(caret)
library(catboost)
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)
```

create train and test data sets:

```
set.seed(1)

tr <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)

trainer <- Sonar[tr,]
tester <- Sonar[-tr,]
```

train models:

```
fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                           number = 3,
                           savePredictions = TRUE,
                           summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                           classProbs = TRUE)

model <- train(x = trainer[,1:60],
               y = trainer$Class,
               method = catboost.caret, 
               trControl = fitControl, 
               tuneLength = 5,
               metric = "ROC")
```

predict using caret:

```
preds1 <- predict(model, tester, type = "prob")
```

save the final model:

```
catboost::catboost.save_model(model$finalModel, "model")
```

load the saved model:

```
model2 <- catboost::catboost.load_model("model")
```

predict using the saved model:

```
preds2 <- catboost.predict(model2,
                           catboost.load_pool(tester),
                           prediction_type = "Probability")
```

check equality of predictions

```
all.equal(preds1[,2], preds2)
```

EDIT: while:

```
saveRDS(model, "caret.model.rds")
model3 <- readRDS("caret.model.rds")
preds3 <- predict(model3, tester, type = "prob")
```

results in R session crash

```
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] mlbench_2.1-1        catboost_0.10.3      caret_6.0-80         ggplot2_2.2.1        lattice_0.20-35      RevoUtils_11.0.0    
[7] RevoUtilsMath_11.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.3.1         magic_1.5-8        ddalpha_1.3.3      tidyr_0.8.1        sfsmisc_1.1-2      jsonlite_1.5      
 [7] viridisLite_0.3.0  splines_3.5.0      foreach_1.5.0      prodlim_2018.04.18 assertthat_0.2.0   stats4_3.5.0      
[13] DRR_0.0.3          yaml_2.1.19        robustbase_0.93-0  ipred_0.9-6        pillar_1.2.3       glue_1.2.0        
[19] digest_0.6.15      colorspace_1.3-2   recipes_0.1.2      htmltools_0.3.6    Matrix_1.2-14      plyr_1.8.4        
[25] psych_1.8.4        timeDate_3043.102  pkgconfig_2.0.1    CVST_0.2-2         broom_0.4.4        purrr_0.2.4       
[31] scales_0.5.0       gower_0.1.2        lava_1.6.1         tibble_1.4.2       withr_2.1.2        nnet_7.3-12       
[37] lazyeval_0.2.1     mnormt_1.5-5       survival_2.41-3    magrittr_1.5       nlme_3.1-137       MASS_7.3-49       
[43] dimRed_0.1.0       foreign_0.8-70     class_7.3-14       tools_3.5.0        data.table_1.11.4  stringr_1.3.1     
[49] plotly_4.7.1       kernlab_0.9-26     munsell_0.4.3      bindrcpp_0.2.2     compiler_3.5.0     RcppRoll_0.2.2    
[55] rlang_0.2.0        grid_3.5.0         iterators_1.0.10   htmlwidgets_1.2    geometry_0.3-6     gtable_0.2.0      
[61] ModelMetrics_1.1.0 codetools_0.2-15   abind_1.4-5        reshape2_1.4.3     R6_2.2.2           lubridate_1.7.4   
[67] dplyr_0.7.5        bindr_0.1.1        stringi_1.1.7      parallel_3.5.0     Rcpp_0.12.17       rpart_4.1-13      
[73] DEoptimR_1.0-8     tidyselect_0.2.4
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. But curious about why it crashes with other saving methods

Comment: Glad to help. As I mentioned in my comment to your question, the fact that this does not work when saving a caret model is worth mentioning in an issue on github.